# Why are my Java threads not running at the same time?

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets

I have an application that is communicating with a UDP server. My application listens on one port (say 1234) and sends on another (say 5678). The UDP server I am communicating with also requires a "heartbeat" ever 5 seconds, for which I create another thread. When my application first starts up, I create the listen thread, then create the heartbeat thread, then I start sending the UDP server message packets. The only thing, however, is that it seems like all the packets I send out finish before the heartbeat thread starts.

Here is what I have for my listener:

```
public class MyListener implements Runnable {
    private volatile boolean run = true;
    private DatagramSocket myDatagramSocket;
    private DatagramPacket myDatagramPacket;
    private byte[] receiveBuffer;
    private int receiveBufferSize;

    @Override
    public void run(){
        while(run){
            try {
                myDatagramSocket = new DatagramSocket(null);
                InetSocketAddress myInetSocketAddress = new InetSocketAddress(1234);
                myDatagramSocket.bind(myInetSocketAddress);

                receiveBuffer = new byte[2047];
                myDatagramPacket = new DatagramPacket(receiveBuffer, 2047);

                myDatagramSocket.receive(myDatagramPacket);
                byte[] data = myDatagramPacket.getData();

                receiveBufferSize = myDatagramPacket.getLength();

                switch(messageID){
                    ...
                }
            } catch (Exception e){
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is what I have for my heartbeat:

```
public class MyHeartbeat implements Runnable {
    private volatile boolean run = true;
    private HeartbeatSenderClass heartbeatSender;

    @Override
    public void run(){
        while(run){
            try {
                TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(5);
                heartbeatSender.sendHeartbeat();
            } catch(Exception e){
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is what I have for my main class:

```
public class MyApp {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        MyListener listener = new MyListener();
        Thread listenerThread = new Thread(listener);
        listenerThread.setName("Listener Thread");
        listenerThread.start();

        MyHeartbeat heartbeat = new MyHeartbeat();
        Thread heartbeatThread = new Thread(heartbeat);
        heartbeatThread.setName("Heartbeat Thread");
        heartbeatThread.start();

        MySender sender = new MySender();
        Thread senderThread = new Thread(sender);
        senderThread.setName("Sender Thread");
        senderThread.start();
    }
}
```

All of my packets are making it to the UDP server, but not smoothly like I would have thought. I would have thought that while I am sending packets to the server, every 5 seconds my heartbeat would be sent out. However, it seems like my heartbeats are going out only after my packets are done sending. Also, I believe I am not getting all of the messages from the UDP server. I say this because I have sniffed the UDP packets on my machine and I see data coming from the server that my receiver is not receiving/processing. Any suggestions?

Comment: can you share the code for Sender?

Comment: Empty `catch` blocks are a very bad idea, as you'll have no way to know if something has gone wrong.  At the very least, call `printStackTrace()` on the exception you're catching.

Comment: @VGR They aren't really empty ... I just didn't feel like typing all of that code in this post.

Comment: @Pshemo Oops ... I fixed that in the post. My actual code is on a non-networked development machine, and I'm having to transcribe from that machine to this internet machine. Sometimes I miss a few things.

Comment: You should try to avoid such problems. It is really hard to stay motivated to help someone in situation when you start copying code example and you that you need first to correct problems not related question. So before you press that button which is responsible for posting your question take your time and make sure that it contains proper [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) without any extra problems.

Comment: When you leave code out of an example, it's helpful if you put _something_ in its place.  Sometimes just '...' is enought.  Or sometimes you can replace a bunch of lines with a fake method call `handleException(...)` or `doLongComputation(...)` etc.

Comment: @Brian the hearbeatSenderClass knows which port the listener is listening to? And also have you tried to send 10 packets with your sender and log how many you have received in your listener?

Comment: @idipous Well, the heartbeat class does not communicate with my listener, it sends heartbeats to the UDP server. I had not thought of sending from my application to my application (as opposed to from my application to the UDP server), but I could try that to see what happens.

Comment: @Brian this is why I asked for the Sender class to be put up here. There are multiple things that you can do in Java in order to synchronize threads starting but from your explanation and code it is not clear exactly what you need to do. At least to someone that does not the particular set up of the UDP server

Answer (score 1):

You have in heartbeat this:

```
 TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(5);
 heartbeatSender.sendHeartbeat();
```

So before sending the very first beat, you wait for 5 seconds. No wonder that the other threads do their job meanwhile.

Comment: Yes, but after 5 seconds, shouldn't the heartbeat be sent again? Isn't that what threads are for?

Comment: You write above: "However, it seems like my heartbeats are going out only after my packets are done sending.". My answer above is an explanation to it.

Comment: But, they are in different threads. They should run at the same time. A bunch of packets, followed by a heartbeat, followed by a bunch of packets, followed by a heartbeat, and so on ...

Comment: Yeah. But if you start all three at once and only one is waiting 5 seconds before doing net trafic, then it is trivial that the other two will send something before the third one.

Answer (score 0):

The DatagramSocket you use to send the packets is a shared resource that is contended between threads, and then if a thread consume too much of that resource, another one may starve. See: [Thread starvation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/starvelive.html)

Also if you are loosing packets, it happens because you can't read as fast as you should. If udp packets arrive faster then they can be read, the queue will discard the remaining.

Under linux, for example you can control the receive buffer with:

```
sudo sysctl -w net.core.rmem_default=26214400
sudo sysctl -w net.ipv4.udp_mem='26214400 26214400 26214400'
sudo sysctl -w net.ipv4.udp_rmem_min=26214400
```

But anyway if we are talking about a sustained loss, **you should consider to have a thread for reading the buffer, a queue and a thread to process the readed data.**

Comment: Any suggestions for reading faster, or is that simply a limit of UDP?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, wouldn't any code that places the data read from the buffer into a queue, take up just as much time as sending the data to a new thread for processing (which is what I am doing in my "switch" statement)?